# Extract only values without key from QuerySet and save them to list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have problem with getting only values from QuerySet.
I have my table:

```
class Temperature(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'temperature'
```

and in views.py:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = list(Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values('time')) 
        temp_values = list(Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values('value'))

        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "temperature": temp_values,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

and with console.log() in html file I'm checking values, currently they are:[image]

But I want to retrive only value, without key. For e.g. :
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**`values_list(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead, and specify `flat=True`, like:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    labels = list(Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values_list('time', flat=True)) 
    temp_values = list(Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values_list('value', flat=True))
    # ...
```

but the above is *not* safe. A queryset is - unless you specify it - unordered. That means that two queries can result in data that does not "match" in the sense that the first `time` value does not per se corresponds to the first `value` value, although this might be atypical behavior (in some/most database systems), you typically never want this to happen. It also here results in two queries, which is not efficient.

You can first fetch the values, and then use `map`s (or `zip`) to make a transpose, like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get(self, request, format=None):
    qs = Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values_list('time', 'value')
    labels = list(map(itemgetter(0), qs))
    temp_values = list(map(itemgetter(1), qs))
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my first and second problem which I was about to face :)

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to use the 'values_list' function instead of 'values', and if you only want one field, use flat=True:

```
temp_values = Temperature.objects.using('sensors').values_list('value', flat=True)
```

Comment: This was what I was searching for! Thank you very much! I was going insane with finding and trying different solutions...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you're looking for [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) instead of `values`.

Also, you probably don't need that `list()` call in there -- it'll just slow things down and waste memory.

Comment: This was really close. This returned values but as a lists